# How to change speaker's microphone volume using windows multimedia api?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, directsound, winmm

I use windows multimedia api to change volume in C++. I use SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar method of IAudioEndpointVolume interface to change the master volumes of speakers and microphones, and it works properly.

I also want to change the microphone volume of speaker programmatically which can be seen in here:

[image]

I want to set microphone value of the speaker to zero programmatically. I've tried SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar method but it is for to change Left/Right channel volume.

How can I change it programmatically?

Regards.

Comment: can u show us ur code?

Comment: I've got the code from [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437537/Muting-all-microphones-on-Vista-Win). It worked properly.  Also the api is [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368062(v=vs.85).aspx)  I think this API can not change microphone level of a speaker, what should I do..

Comment: If the code worked properly, what is the problem? (Of course you can't change the microphone level of a speaker - it would be like changing the apple colour of an orange.)

Comment: The problem is using this api I can only change the value of the speaker level but I want to change the microphone level of a speaker to avoid back loops(infinite) from microphone.   @molbdnilo

Comment: I can change it from the user interface so there should be a way to change it programmatically @molbdnilo

Comment: So the problem is that the code you found that supposedly mutes all microphones, and which you claim works properly, doesn't actually work?

Comment: I have orginated with that code. I did some changes on it but the struct is the same. I can change the microphone and speakers volumes properly(EDataFlow::eRender,EDataFlow::eCapture). The api does not offer a method for changing the microphone level of a speaker, that u can see the attached picture of the topic. If that value is non zero(or lower levels) the speaker begin to recursive echoing. @molbdnilo

Comment: I'm actually seeking a way to change the microphone level of a speaker, the api that I've mentioned is not compulsory. It works fine to change master volumes. @molbdnilo